# Store DB data to hidden field when dynamic button is clicked/selected

Tags: php, html

I have a database table with the col and data like this:

```
btn_id(int) | description (varchar(100)
1           | Assessment
2           | Registration 
3           | Payment
```

and a php code that calls it:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center"> 
    <form action="" method=POST>
      <?php       
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_buttons ORDER BY 1";
        foreach ($PDO->query($sql) as $row) 
        { 
          echo '<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 portfolio-item">';
          echo '<input type="submit" name="desc" value="'.$row['description'].'" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">';
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="btn_selected" value="'.$row['btn_id'].'" >';
          echo '</div>';
        } 
      ?>
   </form>
  </div>
</div>
 echo $_POST['btn_selected'];
```

This will show buttons with the Description form the database as its value.

When I click on ANY button (with the choices from the DB table = Assessment,Registration,Payment), I always get the btn_id of the last data (which is btn_id = 3). How can I be able to output the clicked button's btn_id instead?

Comment: That happens because you have after the loop more than one input-field with the name "btn_selected" and if you hit submit (it doesn't matter which submit) your last inputfield with the name "btn_selected" overwrites the value in your post-array.

Comment: Is there any 'if condition' I can code that only saves the " $row['btn_id'] " to the " btn_selected " button when I click it?

Comment: I think the easiest way in pure php is that you create in your loop the complete form (from <from> to </form>). Then only one form with ohne hidden-input will be send to the server.

Comment: Thanks! It worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form submission, your hidden input field will be the button id.

You can get this field value like the below way in php

```
<?php
    $btn_selected=$_POST['btn_selected'];

    echo "button value--".$btn_selected;
?>
```

your html part will be

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">  
      <?php       
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_buttons ORDER BY 1";
        foreach ($PDO->query($sql) as $row) 
        {
          echo '<form action="" method=POST>'; 
          echo '<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 portfolio-item">';
          echo '<input type="submit" name="desc" value="'.$row['description'].'" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">';
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="btn_selected" value="'.$row['btn_id'].'" >';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</form>';
        } 
      ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the php-code to:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center"> 

      <?php       
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_buttons ORDER BY 1";
        foreach ($PDO->query($sql) as $row) 
        {
          echo '<form action="" method=POST>'; 
          echo '<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 portfolio-item">';
          echo '<input type="submit" name="desc" value="'.$row['description'].'" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">';
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="btn_selected" value="'.$row['btn_id'].'" >';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</form>';
        } 
      ?>
  </div>
</div>
 echo $_POST['btn_selected'];
```

So the btn_selected value just exists ones per form and won't be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert   in the loop. This is so you can only have one hidden file for the whole form. It's output will surely be the btn_id you clicked.